# Insert additional div inside a grid layout of cards when clicked on any card

Tags: angular

Functional requirement:

- The cards are displayed in a grid format dynamically
- On click of any card it'll call 6 more products from the API.
- The new set of products should be inserted rite next to the card which has been clicked.
- The other products in the grid layout of cards has to be shifted to later position on the grid (rite next to newly added products).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct then you need to do following:
When you receive from server new products, you need to insert them next to clicked item.

I assume that you are displaying your grid via ngFor loop and therefore you could implement logic following way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
<card (onclick)="addNew(i)">Card content</card>
</div>
```

And your addNew would look something like this:

```
addNew(index: number) {
this.http.get('url').subscribe(data => this.items.splice(index, 0, ...data);
}
```

With following code `this.items` is list of items that you display in grid. `data` is array of new items. And `this.items.splice(index, 0, ...data)` means that you insert new items next to your clicked item.